# How do I convert data in a single row with multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains data in the below format

[image]

How do I convert this to the following format:

[image]

Comment: kindly share data as text, not pics

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just need to `reshape`

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 3), columns=['Name', 'ID', 'Marks'])
```